# RVM stuck on version 2.3.3

Tags: rvm

I have several versions of Ruby installed via RVM. I have been using Ruby 2.5.0 for a while, but also working on projects at 2.3.3. Every time I open the terminal or a new tab, it switches to version 2.3.3. I have set the default to 2.5.0, but it doesn't respect this.

I finally pushed my last commit that needed 2.3.3 so I thought I could just nuke it and maybe that would fix my problem. One the one hand, it now correctly defaults to 2.5.0, but always with the error:

```
Required ruby-2.3.3 is not installed.
```

What does it take to make RVM switch to the default and stay there? Why would it be hung up on this specific version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it drove me nearly crazy. All symlinks and config files under /usr/local/rvm/config where pointing to 2.5.3, as I set it up to, but I got the same message as you. Turned out there was a .ruby-version file in the project directory that overrode all settings. Updating this file to the correct version did it for me. Hope it helps you too.